# What is the cause of this error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I have a 2 case statments in a MySql Stored Procedure, is it possible that MySql thinks there needs to be a column for each case statement in the table?

Right now the tables have 18 columns, and I have a query that accounts for those 18 columns.

The IMAGE_URL column is only 1 column.

```
     , CASE WHEN IM.DIVISION IN ('C4', 'J3') THEN
    CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg') END AS IMAGE_URL

  , CASE WHEN IM.DIVISION = '30' THEN
    (Select PM.imgUrl FROM stage_product_data.product_match PM 
     WHERE PM.itemno = IM.ITEMNO) END AS IMAGE_URL
```

Comment: I've only seen this error when you try do `INSERT INTO table` and the stuff you try to insert has more or less columns than `table`. The `CASE` statements cannot generate this error.

Comment: Need the entire query to give you a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (possibly) unintentionally creating two columns here, when based on name it appears like you only wanted one. (They're both named `IMAGE_URL`.)

I'd suspect what you wanted was a multiple case:

```
, CASE WHEN IM.DIVISION IN ('C4', 'J3') THEN
    CONCAT(VAR_STORE_URL,VAR_IMAGE_URL,IM.EDPNO,'.jpg') 
  WHEN IM.DIVISION = '30' THEN
    (Select PM.imgUrl FROM stage_product_data.product_match PM 
     WHERE PM.itemno = IM.ITEMNO) 
  ELSE "Something default" END AS IMAGE_URL
```